# Как скрыть div если все li в нем имеют display: none;?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеем такой блок у которого все `li` имеют `style=display: none;`

```html
<div data-css-class="woof_container_pa_ves" class="woof_container woof_container_radio woof_container_pa_ves woof_container_1 woof_container_">
  <h4> вес </h4>
  <div class="woof_block_html_items">
    <ul class="woof_list woof_list_radio">
      <li class="woof_term_55 ">
        <div class="iradio_flat-blue">
          <input type="radio"><ins class="iCheck-helper">
                                </ins>
        </div>
        <label class="woof_radio_label " for="woof_55_5d9cdc4e6a34d">10 см
      <span class="woof_radio_count">(0)</span>
</label>
        <input type="hidden" value="10 см" data-anchor="woof_n_pa_ves_10sm">
      </li>
      <li class="woof_term_56 ">
        <div class="iradio_flat-blue">
          <input type="radio"><ins class="iCheck-helper"></ins>
        </div>
        <label class="woof_radio_label " for="woof_55_5d9cdc4e6a34d">10 см
 <span class="woof_radio_count">(0)</span>
                  </label>
        <input type="hidden" value="10 см" data-anchor="woof_n_pa_ves_10sm">
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Как такому блоку **`woof_container`** тоже задать `display: none;` только если у него **ВСЕ `li`** имеют `display: none;`
таких блоков много
Подскажите решение "старой школы", чтобы это работало во всех браузерах и телефонах,

Answer (score 0):

Если скрыть все li по умолчанию, а ПОКАЗ элемента задавать классом (например '-shown'), то? например на jquery

```
if(!$('.woof_container .-shown')[0]) {
    $('.woof_container ').css('display','none')
}
```

Comment: вы видимо не поняли мне  нужно блоку woof_container тоже задать display: none; только если у него ВСЕ li имеют display: none;

Comment: мне не-надо что-то там скрывать еще , все что надо уже скрывается и показывается

Answer (score 0):

Решение на чистом js .

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var container = document.querySelector('.woof_container');
  var li = container.querySelectorAll('li');
  var equal = false;
  li.forEach(function(item) {
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(item);
    style.display === 'none' ? equal = true : equal = false;
  });
  if (equal) container.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
div li {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div data-css-class="woof_container_pa_ves" class="woof_container woof_container_radio woof_container_pa_ves woof_container_1 woof_container_">
  <h4> вес </h4>
  <div class="woof_block_html_items">
    <ul class="woof_list woof_list_radio">
      <li class="woof_term_55">
        <div class="iradio_flat-blue">
          <input type="radio"><ins class="iCheck-helper">
                                </ins>
        </div>
        <label class="woof_radio_label " for="woof_55_5d9cdc4e6a34d">10 см
      <span class="woof_radio_count">(0)</span>
</label>
        <input type="hidden" value="10 см" data-anchor="woof_n_pa_ves_10sm">
      </li>
      <li class="woof_term_56">
        <div class="iradio_flat-blue">
          <input type="radio"><ins class="iCheck-helper"></ins>
        </div>
        <label class="woof_radio_label " for="woof_55_5d9cdc4e6a34d">10 см
 <span class="woof_radio_count">(0)</span>
                  </label>
        <input type="hidden" value="10 см" data-anchor="woof_n_pa_ves_10sm">
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<li class="woof_term_55">
  внешний li
</li>
```

Comment: У вас здесь ошибка - по сути проверяется, если последний `li` скрыт, тогда скрывается блок.

Comment: у меня это не работает, а мой li выгладит так - <li class="woof_term_55 " style="display: none;">, у меня нет div li {
  display: none;
}

Answer (score 0):

Если на jquery, то можно сделать как-то так:

```
$('.woof_list li:visible').length === 0 ? $('.woof_container').hide() : $('.woof_container').show();
```